# VBA Split String into 2 groups

Tags: vba, split

my string may have short or long name like below

- short: String = "Stack Over Flow"
- long: String = "Stack Over Flow Access VBA Coding"

now I need to split this string into 2 groups as
1st group will have first 3 words **Stack Over Flow** and 2nd group will have **Access VBA Coding**
if the string is short then 2nd group will have blank

below code does not work need your help

```
Dim str As String, Result As String
Dim Start_Point As Long, No_Characters As Long
str = cmbName.Text
Start_Point = InStr(str, " ") + 1
No_Characters = Len(str) - Start_Point

group1 = Left(str, No_Characters + 1)
group2 = Right(str, No_Characters + 1)

MsgBox group1 & " - " & group2
```

Comment: What's the criteria to decide if it is a long string? More than 3 words? What is the criteria to split the string? After 3 words? Or in the middle? Please clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `Limit` parameter of `Split` function like this

```
Private Function SplitInTwo(sText As String) As Variant
    Dim vSplit      As Variant
    Dim sSecond     As String
    
    vSplit = Split(sText, " ", Limit:=4)
    If UBound(vSplit) >= 3 Then
        sSecond = vSplit(3)
        ReDim Preserve vSplit(0 To 2) As String
    End If
    SplitInTwo = Array(Join(vSplit, " "), sSecond)
End Function
```

Here are some use-cases

```
Dim vParts      As Variant

vParts = SplitInTwo("Stack Over Flow")
Debug.Print vParts(0) & " - " & vParts(1)   '--> Stack Over Flow -
vParts = SplitInTwo("Stack Over Flow Access VBA Coding")
Debug.Print vParts(0) & " - " & vParts(1)   '--> Stack Over Flow - Access VBA Coding
```

Comment: I like this attempt. I would a 2nd parameter (maybe optional) to the function so that the number of words that splits the string is not hardcoded. And maybe improve it so that multiple blanks (or tabs) will not break the logic. But OP is very unspecific about what is needed.

Comment: @FunThomas Yes, it is possible for OP to add an extra parameter, now that they are aware how `Limit` parameter of `Split` function works.  Can you provide a sample input that "break the logic"?

Comment: I mean something like `"Stack    Over\tabFlow Access VBA Coding"`

Comment: Cannot understand what you mean but feel free to provide afore mentioned improvement as an additional answer I guess.

Comment: countWords does not give correct answer. str = cmbName.Text
    sWords = Split(str, " ")
    countWords = UBound(sWords)
    
    vParts = SplitInTwo(str)
    MsgBox countWords

Comment: @DilDilshan `UBound(sWords)` is not the amount of words it is the upper bound of an array that starts counting with `0`. So if you have 3 items in your array they are numbered `0`, `1` and `2` so `UBound(sWords)` will give you `2`. The amount of words therefore is always `UBound(sWords) + 1`.